# 3D title Rendering in Maya For babylon Js Game Engine

Tags: 3d, rendering, lighting, maya, babylonjs

I created a 3D title in Maya and applied color through Lambertian shading and rendering with mental ray.

[image: Maya render]

The problem is when the title is rendered in the game engine, it is looking very sad. The colors are faded also the lighting is not the same as Maya's rendered output.

[image: Game render]

Please tell me how can I make the in-game version look more like the result in Maya. I saw lots of 3D games whose titles and objects are very beautiful, bright and colorful with lighting.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the most notably absent elements in your engine render are shadows and ambient occlusion. I am not familiar with babylon.js but found these doc pages that will hopefully help you get closer to matching the Mental Ray output.

https://doc.babylonjs.com/babylon101/shadows

https://doc.babylonjs.com/how_to/using_the_ssao_rendering_pipeline

Comment: Thank you, Ryan. I will try this. :-)